# Index - Constructor for must explicitly initialize the member which does not have a default constructor

Tags: multi-index, table

I try to create two tables and mult_index, I received an error on output.

header file

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosio/asset.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

CONTRACT game : public contract
{
public:
   using contract::contract;

   game(name receiver, name code, datastream<const char *> ds)
       : contract(receiver, code, ds), config(receiver, receiver.value) {}

   ACTION setconf(uint64_t config_id, uint32_t init_energy, uint32_t init_max_energy, uint64_t last_fee_updated, uint8_t fee);
   ACTION newuser(name owner);

   TABLE config_table
   {
      uint64_t config_id;
      uint32_t init_energy;
      uint32_t init_max_energy;
      uint64_t last_fee_updated;
      uint8_t fee;
      uint64_t primary_key() const { return config_id; }
   };

   TABLE accounts_table
   {
      name account;
      uint32_t energy;
      uint32_t max_energy;
      asset balances;
      name primary_key() const { return account; }
   };

   typedef multi_index<name("config"), config_table> config_index;
   typedef multi_index<name("accounts"), accounts_table> accounts_index;

   using setconf_action = action_wrapper<name("setconf"), &game::setconf>;
   using newuser_action = action_wrapper<name("newuser"), &game::newuser>;

   config_index config;
   accounts_index accounts;
};
```

error output:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/game.dir/game.obj
In file included from /wax/mycontract/game/src/game.cpp:1:
/wax/mycontract/game/src/../include/game.hpp:11:4: error: constructor for 'game' must explicitly initialize the member 'accounts' which does not have a default constructor
   game(name receiver, name code, datastream<const char *> ds)
   ^
/wax/mycontract/game/src/../include/game.hpp:43:19: note: member is declared here
   accounts_index accounts;
                  ^
/usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/eosiolib/contracts/eosio/multi_index.hpp:431:7: note: 'eosio::multi_index<3607749779137757184, game::accounts_table>' declared here
class multi_index
```

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of accounts_table, you defined the primary key like this:

```
name primary_key() const { return account; }
```

you need to define it like this:

```
uint64_t primary_key() const { return account.value; }
```